# concatenating elements of n arrays with different array lengths and printing all possible outcomes

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to loop through arrays with different lengths and concatenate their element with each other and print all the possible combinations together!

example code:

```py
arr1 = ["test", "what", "334"]
arr2 = ["_", "-", "#", "*", "()", "$"]
arr3 = ["adf", "ngdda"]
```

I want the output to consist of arr1[element] + arr2[element] + arr3[element] and it would have 3 x 6 x 2 = 36, 36 outcomes.

duo to array lengths being different, I can't use one for-loop or while-loop and because len(arr1) = 3, when calculating the possible outcomes of arr1 + arr2 + arr3, I can only use i < 3 but this makes the for-loop to loop through other arrays 3 times too. and this will make 3 x 3 x 3 outcomes and the others won't be calculated!

I'd appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `product` from the `itertools` built in module https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For
> example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in
> B).

```py
from itertools import product

arr1 = ["test", "what", "334"]
arr2 = ["_", "-", "#", "*", "()", "$"]
arr3 = ["adf", "ngdda"]
results = ["".join(result) for result in product(arr1, arr2, arr3)]

print(len(results))
print(results)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
36
['test_adf', 'test_ngdda', 'test-adf', 'test-ngdda', 'test#adf', 'test#ngdda', 'test*adf', 'test*ngdda', 'test()adf', 'test()ngdda', 'test$adf', 'test$ngdda', 'what_adf', 'what_ngdda', 'what-adf', 'what-ngdda', 'what#adf', 'what#ngdda', 'what*adf', 'what*ngdda', 'what()adf', 'what()ngdda', 'what$adf', 'what$ngdda', '334_adf', '334_ngdda', '334-adf', '334-ngdda', '334#adf', '334#ngdda', '334*adf', '334*ngdda', '334()adf', '334()ngdda', '334$adf', '334$ngdda']
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to combine the strings in different combinations, not just get the combinations.  I also doubt that he is allowed to use itertools for what appears to be a homework problem.

Comment: Yeah only realized they wanted to join them after i seen your answer. updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
arr1 = ["test", "what", "334"]
arr2 = ["_", "-", "#", "*", "()", "$"]
arr3 = ["adf", "ngdda"]
result = []
for i in arr1:
    for j in arr2:
        for k in arr3:
            result.append(i+j+k)

print(len(result)) #36
print(result)
#['test_adf', 'test_ngdda', 'test-adf', 'test-ngdda', 'test#adf', 'test#ngdda', 'test*adf', 'test*ngdda', 'test()adf', 'test()ngdda', 'test$adf', 'test$ngdda', 'what_adf', 'what_ngdda', 'what-adf', 'what-ngdda', 'what#adf', 'what#ngdda', 'what*adf', 'what*ngdda', 'what()adf', 'what()ngdda', 'what$adf', 'what$ngdda', '334_adf', '334_ngdda', '334-adf', '334-ngdda', '334#adf', '334#ngdda', '334*adf', '334*ngdda', '334()adf', '334()ngdda', '334$adf', '334$ngdda']
```